# How do I find bounded functional norm $\| L \|$ and the vector satisfying Riesz representation theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis

Exercise I.2.5 in *A Course in Functional Analysis* written by John B. Conway,

Let $H$ be the collection of all absolutely continuous functions $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(0)=0$, $f'\in L^2(0,1)$ with inner product,
$$ <f,g>= \int_0^1 f'(t) \overline{g'(t)}dt$$
for $f,g\in H$.
If $0<t\le 1$, define $L:H \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $:L(h)=h(t)$.

I have to find $\|L\|$ and the vector $h_0 \in H$ such that $L(h)=<h,h_0>$.

I can't understand why $L(h)$ is the value of inner product. The $L(h)=h(t)$ is a function of $t$ but $<h,h_0>$ is the value of integration from $0$ to $1$.
Furthermore, I also don't know how I get the norm $\|L\|$ since it is supremum of some functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|L(h)|=|h(t)|=|\int_0^{1} h'(t)dt| \leq \sqrt t \sqrt {\int_0^{1} |h'(s)^{2}ds}$. This shows that $\|L || \leq \sqrt t$. To show that equality holds define $h_0(s)=s$ for $ s<t$ and $h_0(s)=t$ for $s \geq t$. Then $h_0 \in H$ and $|L(h_0)|=|h_0(t)|=t$. Also you can check that $\|h_0\|=\sqrt t$. Hence $\|L\| \geq \frac {|L(h_0)|} {\|h_0\|}=\sqrt t$.

Now $ \langle h, h_0 \rangle=\int_0^{1}h'(s)h_o'(s)ds=\int_0^{t}h'(s)ds=h(t)=L(h)$.

Comment: How do I catch that explicit function?

Comment: @Idkwhat We have $h(t)=\int_0^{t}h'(x)dx$ we want $h(t)=\int_0^{1} h'(x)h_0'(x)dx$. So I took $h_0'(x)=1$ for $x <t$ and $0$ for $x >t$. I then integrated $h_0'$ to write down my definition of $h_0(x)$.